# accessing the content of a memory address in C

Tags: c, memory-access

i've been trying to figure this out for hours, been driving me a bit crazy. 
i keep getting a segmentation fault when executing the program, how can i fix that?
i also get a warning "trying to pointer from integer of different size" but when i use the
casting (int *) i still get the warning. help please...
here's the code:

---

```
int address, length, i;
int * p = malloc(sizeof(int));

printf("Please enter <address> <length>\n");
scanf("%x %d", &address, &length);
p = (int *) address;

for (i=0; i<length;i++){
 printf( "%02x ", p[i] );
}
```

Comment: Trying to fix *what*?

Comment: Which useful problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Voting to close, try re-phrasing as a question.

Answer (score 1):

This should "work" - of course, you still have to enter a valid address, or the code will crash because you are trying to read from an address you can't read from - there is nothing you can do about that, short of rewriting the part of the operating system that handles "you tried to read memory that doesn't exist or doesn't belong to you".

```
uintptr_t address;
int length, i;
int *p;

 // No need to malloc here. malloc(sizeof(int));

printf("Please enter <address> <length>\n");
scanf("%" PRIxPTR " %d", &address, &length);
p = (int *) address;

for (i=0; i<length;i++){
 printf( "%02x ", p[i] );
}
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that even if this *does* work, it seems to rely quite heavily upon coincidence rather than logic. Not all segfaults are caused by *"you tried to read memory that doesn't exist or doesn't belong to you"*; Perhaps the address entered points to allocated memory owned by the process, but isn't suitably aligned to point to an `int`. +1 for `uintptr_t`.

Comment: Depending on the processor, it may also cause "bus error", which is another word for "unaligned access", yes. Typically, that's treated differently from segault, but yes, it's entirely possible to enter values that lead to OTHER faults than "you can't read this memory because it's not there". Not sure what error you get if the address is non-canonical on x86 (that is, the unused upper bits between 48 and 63 in the word are not the same as bit 47).

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to fix here. You are trying to access a nonexistent memory address or you have no rights to access.

Read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault#Common_causes

Comment: thatnks. so the code is alright? what about the warning i get?

Comment: May be the size of pointer is 64 bit. Then you are trying to cast 32bit `int` to 64bit pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`p = &address;` or `memcpy(p,&address,sizeof(int))`, `instead of p = (int *) address;`

Also if length greater than 1, there may be segmentation fault at

```
for (i=0; i<length;i++){
 printf( "%02x ", p[i] );
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i need to access the memory location that is represented by the value in "address". if i use p=&address that would just give me the memory location of "address" and not it's  value.

Comment: Perhaps you should read a little more about virtual memory... and OSes... and security... and C programming... and give it another try in ten years time, once you've solved some *useful* problems using C.

Comment: make sure that the address has read write permission